# Can I have a C routine, which prevents free()ing the memory twice?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory-management, free

Often in projects, complex structures are used, e.g., like the one below:

```
struct opts {
    char* server;
    char* port;
    int protocol;
    void* protocol_data;
};
```

And to free such structures, till today I adopted the routines as below:

```
void free_proto1(struct opts* opt);
void free_proto2(struct opts* opt);

void free_opts(struct opts** opt) {

    free((*opt)->server);
    free((*opt)->port);

    if ((*opt)->protocol == PROTOCOL1) {
        free_proto1(*opt);
    }
    else if ((*opt)->protocol == PROTOCOL2) {
        free_proto2(*opt);
    }
    else
        free((*opt)->protocol_data);

    free(*opt);
    *opt = NULL;
}
```

But If I have another `struct opts` pointer like `struct opts* opts2 = opts1`, another call to `free_opts(&opt2)` after calling `free_opts(&opt1)` would definitely result in a program crash. I know a good habit of coding is to avoid such calls. But is there by any chance, I could detect that the memory is already freed? I am interested in even looking into `Process Control Block` (That is where I think all the program information resides). Can I scrutinize the PCB structures, before performing a `free()`'ing operations, so that I can avoid `free()`'ing the memory twice?

Comment: There's no way to prevent a situation like you describe, you simply have to document your API and tell users of it to not be stupid. If they then do something stupid, then it's their fault.

Comment: Yes, just create your own functions to allocate and free, which keep an index about which memory blocks have been allocated.

Comment: `#define FREE(A) do { free(A); A = NULL; } while (0)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am not completely aware of how the Linux kernel manages the process in memory, but I believe it stores the memory allocated information somewhere. If it stores, cant we access it before performing free()ing operation?

Comment: @qrdl That is a quite handy macro, but if the structure has pointers as I showed, you would probably be relying on a garbage collector for freeing that memory. And, my worry is when the same FREE(B) is called again (B = A), then the program crashes.

Comment: @vll Are you suggesting to maintain a list of allocated memories for that structure, and remove the entries from the list when the memory is freed for the first time?

Comment: @MohithReddy C does not have a garbage collector.

Comment: @MohithReddy if the pointers in the struct are set NULL the another free will not do anything.

Comment: @P__J__ Oops! I was never aware of that. So I shouldn't be reckless when exiting the functions, which allocated memory on the heap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, C has no support for [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) like f.e. C++ has.

In C, you always have to be careful to not cause memory leaks.

---

Anyway, You can f.e. provide another parameter in the manner of [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). This has the downside that you need to pass the amount of reference pointers to the allocated memory as argument everytime you call `free_opts` and the amount have to be fixed, but it is an approach to help you out.

The memory is only freed, if *all* references have been "pseudo-freed".

All passed reference pointers, except the last one, are just made a null pointer and the pointed memory is in fact not freed until the last reference pointer has been past.

```
int free_opts (struct opts** opt, int ref) {

    static int cnt = 0; 
    cnt++;

    if ( cnt != ref ) {        
        *opt = NULL;
        return 0;
    }

    free((*opt)->server);
    free((*opt)->port);

    if ((*opt)->protocol == PROTOCOL1) {
        free_proto1(*opt);
    }
    else if ((*opt)->protocol == PROTOCOL2) {
        free_proto2(*opt);
    }
    else
        free((*opt)->protocol_data);

    free(*opt);
    return 1;
}
```

Whether the memory is actually freed or not, is indicated by the return value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reference counted API, ie: adding a `size_t refs` field to your struct, and then add a

```
struct opts* ref_opts(struct opts* opt)
```

API that will increase ref counter and return opt; finally, renaming free_opts to unref_opts() and only actually free your structure when refs field is 0.

This will expose a known API to take a structure reference and to free it, in a very homogeneous way; it will be users' fault if they do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

When freeing set the pointer to the known invalid value - usually NULL.

Then even if you free more than one time - `free` ignores NULL pointers.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question well or you concluded from the question title   :(.  I am indeed setting the pointer to NULL, but if free() is called on another pointer which is pointing to the free'ed address, this is my scenario.

Comment: A solution is to have a delete function that take a pointer, you free the value of the pointer and set the value to null.

Comment: @MohithReddy it is a sign of the bad software design. There is no way to save you from bad programming other than to change the way you program.

Answer (score 0):

@RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio and @Federico suggested some reliable methods of preventing the memory `free`'ing twice. But I feel like the suggestion made by @vll should not be lost in the comments, thus I am summarizing the poster suggestion as an answer.

Another reliable way of keeping track of the pointers is to maintain a `list` of the allocated addresses, and free them only when they are on the list. Below is the bare minimal implementation:

```
#include "list.h"

static struct list addr_list;

struct opts* create_opts(void) {

    struct opts* opts = (struct opts*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct opts));

    if (opts == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Initialize the opts{} */

    list_append(&addr_list, opts);

    return opts;
}

int free_opts(struct opts* opts) {

    if (in_list(&addr_list, opts) == false)
        return 0;

    /* Free the opts{} */

    list_remove(&addr_list, opts);

    return 1;
}
```

Of course, the above implementation simply turns down the request of freeing the `structs`, which are not created using `create_opts()`. A partial solution to that can be using flags to enable force cleaning as such. But I hope, someone if at all it is possible will come with some concrete answer.

Thanks to everyone for all the valuable suggestions :)